# Retrieve UIImage from UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, mkmapview

I need to create a `UIImage` from a `MKMapView` (`UIView`). But I do not want to cover the whole `UIView` but only a part of it, to be exact I want the image to be **200x200** pixels and the center of the image should be the user location on the map.

I created a `UIView` Category and tried the following but it won't work. I get an image but the user location is not the center of the image. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(MKMapView *)map
{
    CGPoint newCenter = [map convertCoordinate:map.userLocation.coordinate toPointToView:map];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(newCenter.x-100.0, newCenter.y-100.0, 200.0, 200.0);
    NSLog(@"%f,@%f",rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

The image always starts at the left top corner at the moment, although my coordinates are right when I `NSLog` them.

Comment: Is the user location centered in the map view?

Comment: yes it is. i use the 'MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading' and then i call '    [map setCenterCoordinate:map.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
' so the user location is centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply a transform to the context to move the content you want to the correct position before you render it.

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
```